Clarification on Definition 3.1 of Bochner Integrable Functions
In section 3 of the paper Integrals with Values in Banach Spaces and Locally Convex Spaces by Piotr Mikusiński, the following definitions appear:


Definition 2.3 (Simple Functions) A function $f: X \to \mathbb{E}$ (where $\mathbb{E}$ is a Banach space) is called a simple function if it can be written as:
$$f = v_1 A_1 + \dots + v_n A_n$$
where $A_1, \dots, A_n \in R$ and $v_1, \dots, v_n \in \mathbb{E}$, with $R$ being a ring of subsets of $X$. The ring $R$ is closed under finite unions and differences of sets. The vector space of all simple $\mathbb{E}$-valued functions is denoted by $\mathcal{S}(\mathbb{E})$. For a simple function $f = v_1 A_1 + \dots + v_n A_n$, the integral of $f$ with respect to a measure is defined as:
$$\int f = v_1 \mu(A_1) + \dots + v_n \mu(A_n)$$
This integral is well-defined and linear.



Definition 3.1 (Bochner Integrable Functions)
A function $f: X \to \mathbb{E}$ is called Bochner integrable if there exist simple functions $f_n \in \mathcal{S}(\mathbb{E})$ such that:
(a) $\sum_{n=1}^\infty |f_n|_1 < \infty$,
(b) $f(x) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty f_n(x)$ at those points $x \in X$ where $\sum_{n=1}^\infty |f_n(x)| < \infty$.
If these conditions are satisfied, we write $f \sim f_1 + f_2 + \dots$ or $f \sim \sum_{n=1}^\infty f_n$.


I would like clarification on the meaning of part (b) of Definition 3.1. In particular, why is that condition necessary, and how does it relate to the usual definition of an integrable function?

It would be helpful to include some more information, such as what $X$ and $E$ are, what $Sp(E)$ is and what $|\cdot |_{1}$ is.

@DeanMiller will do!

I haven't checked the details, but I think essentially (a) + (b) implies this sequence of simple functions converges to $f$ pointwise almost everywhere in the measure, so that you can define the integral using simple functions, and this coincides with the intuition you have in usual Lebesgue integration.

Adding to the previous comment, a more common definition of Bochner integral (eg. in wiki) is: define "strong measurability" first and for strongly measurable functions, if $\int |s_k-f| d\mu \to 0$ for some sequence of simple functions ${s_k}$, then $f$ is integrable. In this definition, convergence $\mu$-a.e. is free. Your definition is probably the same just stated in a slightly different way. Intuitively, (a) implies tail of the sequence is eventually close to $0$ $\mu$-a.e. and (b) forces the value to agree with $f$ $\mu$-a.e.

For the first question, note that condition (a) is some sort of completeness condition (think about how a normed space is complete if every absolutely convergent series converges), but it does not say anything about how the sequence $(f_{n})_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ relates to $f$. It can be shown by an argument involving the monotone convergence theorem that condition (a) implies $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} |f_{n}(x)| < \infty$ for almost all $x\in X$. Consequently, it can be deduced from condition (b) that the sequence of partial sums $(\sum_{k=1}^{n} f_{k} )_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ converges almost everywhere to $f$. So condition (b) plays the role of relating $f$ to the sequence $(f_{n})_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$.
For the second question, recall that for each Lebesgue integrable function $f:X\to \mathbb{C}$ there is a sequence $(s_{n})_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ of simple functions, each of which vanish outside a set of finite measure, with two notable properties. One property of the sequence $(s_{n})_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is that it converge almost everywhere to $f$ and another is that it forms a Cauchy sequence with respect to the $|\cdot |_{1}$-seminorm, where the seminorm is given by
\begin{equation}
|u|_{1} = \int_{X} |u|
\end{equation}
for any Lebesgue integrable function $u:X\to\mathbb{C}$. In fact, the functions with the existence of a corresponding sequence $(s_{n})_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ which have the relevant properties mentioned above characterise the Lebesgue integrable functions. Note that if you replace $\mathbb{C}$ with a Banach space $E$, this is one of the standards ways to define what it means for a function $f:X\to E$ to be Bochner integrable.
Here is an outline of how the different definitions of Bochner integrability relate. If you have a sequence $(s_{n})_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ of simple functions, each of which vanish outside a set of finite measure, where the sequence converges almost everywhere to $f$ and forms a Cauchy sequence with respect to the $|\cdot |_{1}$-seminorm, then the Cauchy condition implies there is a subsequence $(u_{n_{k}})_{k\in\mathbb{N}}$ such that $|u_{n_{k+1}} - u_{n_{k}}|_{1} \leq 2^{-k}$ for each $k\in\mathbb{N}$. Now define $f_{1} := u_{n_{1}}$ and $f_{n_{k}} := u_{n_{k}} - u_{n_{k-1}}$ for each $k\in\mathbb{N}\setminus\{1\}$. Then with some work you can show that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} |f_{n}|_{1} < \infty$ as well as that both $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} |f_{n}(x)|< \infty$ and $f(x) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} f_{n}(x)$ hold for almost all $x\in X$.
On the other hand, suppose $(f_{n})_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is a sequence of simple functions, each of which vanish outside a set of finite measure, such that the conditions from your definition of Bochner integrable functions apply to this sequence. With some work it can be shown that the condition $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} |f_{n}|_{1} < \infty$ implies that condition (b) in your definition holds for almost all $x\in X$. Define $u_{n} := \sum_{k=1}^{n} f_{k}$ for each $n\in\mathbb{N}$. Then it can be verified that the sequence $(u_{n})_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ converges to $f$ almost everywhere and is Cauchy with respect to the $|\cdot |_{1}$-seminorm.
